# What picture comes into you mind when you read the word " hotware "?

Tags: word-choice

I would like to use this as a brand name for my upcoming products. " Hot ware " - hot everywhere. Heated clothing. Does it sound like that or the picture that conjures up in your mind's eye is a totally different visual association?

Thank you for playing this little word game with me. It helps a lot!

Have a great day!

Comment: My first thought was pots and pans for cooking.

Comment: Then it's not just me. Thank you:D

Comment: Ovenware or cookware usable at high temperatures, e.g. Le Creuset - "All cast iron products with a stainless steel knob, metallic knob or cast iron handles can be used in a conventional oven up to 260°C"

Comment: Very precise Michael. I think I will discard this idea for clothing. How about HotVentures?

Answer (score 3):

"Ware" is very different from "wear".

*Wares* are basically and *goods* for sale. They are normally tangible, non-perishable things such as *hardware* (eg cooking utensils).

"Hotware" makes me think of hardware designed to resist heat. It doesn't make me think of clothes.

Also note that 'hot' has other meanings in the context of fashion. It can mean that clothing is currently fashionable. It can also mean clothing is provocative. Even 'Hotwear' would not necessarily convey what you mean.

Have you considered '*Hotwearables*'? 'Wearable' is a relatively recent term for things that can be worn which may not normally be worn.